# React js Background Image

Tags: css, reactjs

I am currently working on a simple react image that will have profile pictures of different user. I have run into an issue when I try to set the background image. I will have two background images but I am unable to place any.
The images are in my public/images/ but nothing is showing up in the webpage.

I am adding the image in body{} in the CSS file "App.css".

App.css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: var(--fontFamily);
  font-size: var(--fontSize);
  background-image: "url(/images/bg-pattern-top.svg)";
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: top;
}
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import PorfileCard from './PorfileCard';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    <PorfileCard/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[image: File Structure]

[image: Chrome Development Tool]

[image: Chrome React Tool]

Comment: Remove the quotes around "url(/images/bg-pattern-top.svg)". Also please read this page in its entirety. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also to help you debug in the future: open the chrome developer tools and inspect the body element and look at the CSS. It will help you find out of the CSS isn't getting applied or if you have invalid rules.

Comment: Thanks I updated the question with more images of the google chrome dev tool and react tool.

Comment: Re-read the first sentence in my comment :P Also, the error is right there in the CSS rule, you shouldn't include a screenshot of it, you should get familiar with how to see and debug the error

Comment: The problem is the placement of the quotes per @AndyRay. You have: `background-image: "url(/images/bg-pattern-top.svg)";` it should be `background-image: url(/images/bg-pattern-top.svg);` I would also remove the leading slash as that could cause a path error depending on server setup.

Comment: removing the quotes has created a "Failed to compile" error. Changed it to this background-image: url(images/bg-pattern-top.svg); and the error is  Error: Can't resolve '/images/bg-pattern-top.svg'

Comment: CSS doesn't need the quotes but react might want them. If so it would be inside the (). Eg `background-image: URL('image/path');`

Comment: Still returns failed to compile error when I place the quotes inside .

Answer (score 2):

The only way I was able to resolve this was via using inline styling on the main div in app.js.

```
import './App.css';
import PorfileCard from './PorfileCard';

function App() {
  const mystyle = {
    backgroundImage: "url(/images/bg-pattern-top.svg)",
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat"
    
  }
  return (
    <div style={ mystyle }>
     <PorfileCard/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```